# JTextPane not appending string from another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have created 2 classes **urlTestUI.java** and **TestRun.java**. One is created with Window Builder in Eclipse and the other is normal class.
The problem is when i call a method from TestRun with a button click on urlTestUI, The string from TestRun is not displaying JTextPane.
The string from UI class is appending to JTextPane but not the string from other class.

urlTestUI.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class urlTestUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    static urlTestUI window;
//  AppendingTextPane atp = new AppendingTextPane();
    AppendTextPane atp1= new AppendTextPane();
    SwingWorker<Object, String> worker;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
//      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    window = new urlTestUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public urlTestUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 822, 473);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Start");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                          
                TestRun tr =new TestRun();
                tr.method1();
                atp1.appendText("helloText1");
                };
                
            
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(367, 111, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 169, 790, 258);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        
        scrollPane.setViewportView(atp1);
    }

public class AppendTextPane extends JTextPane {
    JTextPane textpane;
    
//  public AppendTextPane(JTextPane textpane) {
//      this.textpane=textpane;
//  }


    public void appendText(String str) {
//      Document doc = getDocument();
        StyledDocument doc = getStyledDocument();
        Style style = doc.addStyle("MyStyle", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.BLACK);
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 12);
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Arial");
        try {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), str, style);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Extended class TestRun.java

```
public class TestRun extends urlTestUI {
//  AppendingTextPane atp=new AppendingTextPane();
    boolean isSomthing=true;
    
    public void method1() {
        
        if(isSomthing=true) {
            atp1.appendText("helloText2");
            System.out.println("helloText3");
        }else {
            System.out.println("helloText4");
            atp1.appendText("helloText5");
        }
    }
    
    public void method2() {
        atp1.appendText("helloTest6");
    }

}
```

The string from UI class is appending to JTextPane.
[image: The UI]

The method from other class is running on button click and showing system out on eclipse console
[image: Eclipse console]

Note:JTextArea is not used because i need to add text colour in future

Comment: You need to pass a reference to the text pane as a parameter to your TestRun class so that you can update the text pane that is displayed in your frame.

Comment: Don’t extend from urlTestUI. While you can pass a reference of the text pane to test run class an onserver pattern would be betttrr

Answer (score 0):

Doing `public class TestRun extends urlTestUI {` isn't going to give you access to the instance of `atp1` which was created by `window = new urlTestUI();` and which is on the screen.

Instead, `TestRun` either needs some reference to the instance of `urlTestUI`, or the text pane, which is on the screen.

Although, a better solution would be to use a observer pattern, maybe in a "producer/consumer" form, so that `TestRun` was decoupled from `urlTestUI` and you could better support the single responsibility principle (is it really `TestRun` responsibility to be modifying the text pane??)

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        AppendTextPane textPane = new AppendTextPane();

        /**
         * Create the application.
         */
        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Start");
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    Producer tr = new Producer(new Producer.Consumer() {
                        @Override
                        public void didProduce(String text) {
                            try {
                                textPane.appendText(text);
                            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    tr.method1();
                    try {
                        textPane.appendText("helloText1");
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            ;

            });
            add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            textPane = new AppendTextPane();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
            add(scrollPane);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }

    public class AppendTextPane extends JTextPane {
        public void appendText(String str) throws BadLocationException {
            StyledDocument doc = getStyledDocument();
            Style style = doc.addStyle("MyStyle", null);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.BLACK);
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 12);
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Arial");
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), str, style);
        }
    }

    public class Producer {
        boolean isSomthing = true;

        public interface Consumer {
            public void didProduce(String text);
        }

        private Consumer consumer;

        public Producer(Consumer consumer) {
            this.consumer = consumer;
        }

        public Consumer getConsumer() {
            return consumer;
        }

        public void method1() {
            Consumer consumer = getConsumer();
            if (consumer == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (isSomthing = true) {
                consumer.didProduce("helloText2");
            } else {
                consumer.didProduce("helloText4");
            }
        }

        public void method2() {
            Consumer consumer = getConsumer();
            if (consumer == null) {
                return;
            }
            consumer.didProduce("helloTest6");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have much idea about 'observer pattern', i tried  a little.... your above code shows many errors on Eclipse.

Comment: About your question.... Here I only posted an example program, my actual program contains so many buttons and codes to write excel files...etc. Using all those codes in one file is complicated. If you can help me with 'reference to the instance' it's very helpful... Thanks for the reply

Comment: @naveenjtrn The code I posted compiles and runs for me. [Passing information to a method or a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) is Java 101 and you really should know about it before delving into something as complex as Swing

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code on `TestRun.java`:

```
public TestRun(AppendTextPane textpane) {
    this.atp1=textpane;
}
```

[image: Screenshot1]

And atp1 reference in `urlTestUI.java` like this:

[image: Screenshot2]